# Getting error for line of code. What should i Import?

Tags: java, opengl, jogl

im getting an error for line 20(labeled) For .createGLCanvas i get an error saying " The method createGLCanvas(GLCapabilities) is undefined for the type GLDrawableFactory" What does this mean? Did i not import something i was suppose to import?

```
import javax.media.opengl.*;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import javax.media.opengl.GL;
import javax.media.opengl.GLAutoDrawable;
import javax.media.opengl.GLCanvas;
import javax.media.opengl.GLEventListener;
import java.awt.Canvas;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class Forest{//open forest

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Frame frame = new Frame("Hello World");

20:    GLCanvas canvas = GLDrawableFactory.getFactory().createGLCanvas(new GLCapabilities());
    frame.add(canvas);

    frame.setSize(300, 300);
    frame.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

    frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter()
    {
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)
        {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });

    frame.show(); 

}//close forest
}
```

Comment: It appears that there is no such method like createGLCanvas(new GLCapabilities()) in class GLDrawableFactory. Check that thing first, does it exists. Or does this method suppose to take any Parameters, if yes then what kind of parameters can it take.

Comment: It is a matter of reading the error message.

Comment: I don't this that it's that simple - as @AlexR noted there is such method. There must be a conflict in classpath JARs or something -- and no need to downvote

Comment: Perhaps there is a conflict. Im using 4 Jars gluegen.jar rt.jar  jogl.jar and android.jar. Is it possible that they are conflicting each other?

Answer (score 1):

It means there is no method called `createGLCanvas` on [GLDrawableFactory](http://download.java.net/media/jogl/jogl-2.x-docs/javax/media/opengl/GLDrawableFactory.html). So you need to figure out what to call.

Comment: I think AlexR is correct, I didn't notice the javax.media.opengl imports, and I mistook it for JOGL.

Comment: it is JOGL and How do i figure out what to call?

Comment: Find tutorials, examples or other documentation. The API javadocs will be helpful, but it looks like there are multiple versions out there, so make sure you know exactly what you're working with and that you're reading relevant documentation.

Answer (score 1):

The point is that according to [javadoc](http://download.java.net/media/jogl/builds/archive/jsr-231-beta1/javadoc_public/javax/media/opengl/GLDrawableFactory.html) this method should be supported:

`GLCanvas  createGLCanvas(GLCapabilities capabilities)`

I think that you should check again your classpath. What jar are you working with? Where have you downloaded it from? What is the jar version? Check all this and use appropriate API doc that describes *your* version of the library when you are writing code.

Comment: im working with gluegen.jar rt.jar and jogl.jar. But how would i support this method @alexr?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this thread](http://www.java-gaming.org/index.php?topic=16220.0), the correct way to do this is now `GLCanvas canvas = new GLCanvas();`. This seems to represent an API change.